# How to load jQuery with Ajax in WP version 5.3.2?

Tags: theme-development, ajax, jquery

I am building a custom theme and using `wp_enqueue_scripts` to load a custom JS file for a specific page template.  As you can see I declared `jquery` as a dependency...

```
function enqueue_theme_scripts() {
  if (is_page_template('template-contact.php')) {
    wp_enqueue_script(
      'template-contact-js',
      get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/template-contact.js',
      array('jquery'),
      false,
      true
    );
  }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_theme_scripts');
```

This is what I have in the JS file...

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log($);
    console.log($.ajax);  
  });
})(jQuery);
```

This is what the 'console' tab shows...

[image: Screenshot of Chrome Inspector console tab]

jQuery is loaded, but the `$.ajax` method is not included.

This is what the 'sources' tab in the Inspector shows...

[image: screenshot of jQuery 3.4.1 loaded in Chrome's inspector]

As you can see it is loading jQuery version 3.4.1, but line 48 seems to indicate that ajax is being removed.  How do I get jquery to load with the ajax method included?

Comment: jQuery 3.4.1 is not the version bundled with WordPress. Another plugin or your theme must have replaced it with its own version.

Comment: @JacobPeattie You are correct.  I found it.  Post this as an answer, so I can give you points.